# What is the difference between vapor and liquid with same temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, equilibrium, phase-diagram

When the temperature is same, it means that the kinetic energy of the particles of both phases are the same,
so what is the difference between a vapor and liquid of a substance, such as ethanol, when they are in  the same temperature?

Comment: The vapor is in gas phase, so it is a gas.

Comment: well, they are at different density to begin with. As a result, their local structure is different, which also deeply affects the kinetics.

Comment: I think you mean "liquid", not "fluid". A gas is also a fluid.

Comment: A vapor is a suspension of liquid particles in a gas. Ethanol in air can exist as a vapor and as a mixture, depending on how the ethanol is introduced into the air (such as atomization) and what the temperatures are of the ethanol and air. It cannot exist for long as a vapor if the air is not fully saturated with gaseous ethanol.

Comment: Their specific heat capacity is different. :)

Comment: *“When the temperature is same, it means that the kinetic energy of the particles of both phases are the same”* This is incorrect. Where did you hear this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As silly as it sounds, the difference is that one is a gas, and the other is a liquid. The vapour has the properties of a gas, i.e. it expands as much as it likes, it compresses according to certain laws, etc. The liquid has different properties. Effectively, they will look different, as you imagine a liquid and a gas being different. The gas will be a gas, the liquid a liquid.

The problem here, is that you think the phase of a substance is a *function* of its temperature only. This is not necessarily the case. I can heat ice up to 0 C, and it will still be ice. Conversely, I can cool water down to 0 C, and it will still be water. To have it actually *go across* the critical point, I have to spend some additional energy, called [**latent heat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat).

A critical point is a value of temperature (and pressure, and whatever else) where the two states of matter *coexist*.

Comment: What kind of energy is latent heat?

Comment: For example, it may be needed to break the bonds of the crystalline lattice, in the case of a solid to liquid transition.